# Flickering backdrop filter blur on scaling

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a simple card which zooms on hovering. The card text has a backdrop blur. When I hover the card, the transition goes smoothly, but the bottom edges of the text container seem to flicker.

```css
.card{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg");
    margin: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    will-change: transform;
}

.card:hover{
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card-details{
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255/60%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-details">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a long-standing Chromium [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=986206).

Comment: Any hacks around it?

Comment: No, none that I've seen yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to using `border: 2px solid transparent;` for the entire card, this will prevent flickering, but you will get a border instead of a flickering effect. If you try to change the color of the border, you will get back a flikering effect.

Another way, more complicated, you will need to add a pseudo-element to the **card-details** class, then move `backdrop-filter`, `background-color` to the pseudo-element.

##### UPDATED

It also works with `padding: 2px` instead of `border: 2px solid transparent;`

[image]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card,
.card2,
.card3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg');
  /* margin: 25px; */
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card2 {
  border: 2px solid transparent; /* trick */
}

.card:hover,
.card2:hover,
.card3:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card-details {
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255/60%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.card-details3 {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border: 2px solid transparent; /* trick */
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-details3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255/60%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-details">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="card2">
  <div class="card-details">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="card3">
  <div class="card-details3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```